# HTACCESS deny folder for all visitors except one IP and Log IP of denied visitors?

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

**HTACCESS** deny folder for all visitors except one `IP` and `Log IP` of denied visitors?

I have tried using the following code in htaccess

**code--HTACCESS**

```
RewriteEngine On

order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from a.b.c.d

ErrorDocument 404 logip.php

ErrorDocument 400 logip.php

ErrorDocument 403 logip.php


ErrorDocument 500 http://www.mndf.gov.mv/mndf/postern/getit.php
```

and on **logip.php** I used the following..

```
include '../include/connect.php'; 
//this will get your ip  
$date=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');  
$ip="$_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR]";  

$dequery = "insert into IPLog(IP,Date) values('$ip','$date')";
$ex = mysql_query($dequery);
header('location:../index.php');
```

---

this only log the ip a.b.c.d and the time.

how can i get other ip from which the visitors have tried to access the url or subdirectory?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing 401 (Authorization Required)

```
RewriteEngine On

order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from a.b.c.d

ErrorDocument 404 /logip.php

ErrorDocument 400 /logip.php

ErrorDocument 401 /logip.php

ErrorDocument 403 /logip.php


ErrorDocument 500 http://www.mndf.gov.mv/mndf/postern/getit.php
```

For more info on error codes check out this page: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Also, you should use the absolute path of the ErrorDocument (like /logip.php instead of just logip.php), as at this point it will try to redirect to logip.php in the directory that they're not authorized to access whereas you want them to go to the document root (and have the script in the document root if you don't already).

Information on this can be found here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument